# VS2005 C++ compiler problem including <comdef.h> in MFC application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, compiler-construction, mfc

I am having some trouble converting an old project from VS6 to VS2005. At one place in the code it uses the type variant_t so it includes comdef.h for this purpose. comdef.h then includes comutil.h which generates these errors for me:

```
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\comutil.h(978) : error C2535: '_variant_t::_variant_t(int) throw()' : member function already defined or declared
    c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\comutil.h(970) : see declaration of '_variant_t::_variant_t'
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\comutil.h(1007) : error C2535: '_variant_t::operator int(void) const' : member function already defined or declared
    c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\comutil.h(998) : see declaration of '_variant_t::operator int'
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\comutil.h(1037) : error C2535: '_variant_t &_variant_t::operator =(int)' : member function already defined or declared
    c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\comutil.h(1029) : see declaration of '_variant_t::operator ='
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\comutil.h(1331) : error C2084: function '_variant_t::_variant_t(int) throw()' already has a body
    c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\comutil.h(970) : see previous definition of '{ctor}'
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\comutil.h(1588) : error C2084: function '_variant_t::operator int(void) const' already has a body
    c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\comutil.h(998) : see previous definition of '.H'
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\comutil.h(2006) : error C2084: function '_variant_t &_variant_t::operator =(int)' already has a body
    c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\comutil.h(1029) : see previous definition of '='
```

There is probably some configuration that is incorrect, some define missing or some include file I should have included but I can't seem to find the problem. Any pointers in the right direction is much appreciated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Does your own code do something like this:

```
#define long int
```

Comment: Haha, you where right! when I searched around for defines I found this:

    #ifdef WIN32
    #define bool int
    #define true 1
    #define false 0
    typedef int ssize_t;
    #define RET "\r\n";

    #define mystring CString

    #endif

Horrible working on old code sometimes! But huge thanks!

Comment: add what if with this #define another errors occur ? it might help for small, very small projects; but not for large once. e.g it does not help me. it has another point, because two projects i have one of them compiles and runs well, another gives this error.

Comment: icaptan, with this #define the original error occured, which Dan asked for help with. Dan said I was right and he fixed it. He probably deleted it so the error went away. Now icaptan you ask, if with this #define other errors occur. The answer is the same, right? Delete this #define and other errors will also go away? Though it depends on what the errors are. Different errors need different fixes.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like one of two things, an include order problem or as you stated something not getting defined but I am leaning towards the first one. You might want to check msdn and make sure there are no restrictions on when comutil.h can be included (I know this is an issue if you include winsock2.h before windows.h). There is also an option under C/C++ > Advanced to Show Includes (/showIncludes option from the command-line) which is generally helpful when trying to track issues like this down.